# c# how long does it take to start a task

Tags: c#, performance, time, task

Just wondering how long does the task creation take:

```
Task<int> tsk = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadOscilloscopeData(2, val.ADC_PSC, val.ADC_ARR, val.ADCSAMPLES, val.ADCFRAMES, val.NCHANNELS, 1000, out outdata));
```

Comment: Check by using a Stopwatch class

Comment: It depends on many things because a task is scheduled and the scheduler will decide when it is the best time to run that task

Comment: What timespan do you want to know? When Task.TaskFactory.StartNew will return or when the task start to run?

Comment: Just wanted to know. Now that is about 3ms and I will take it into account.

Comment: @Sir Rufo no - but I can stop stopwatch in the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use stopwatch to see?

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
Task<int> tsk = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadOscilloscopeData(2, val.ADC_PSC, val.ADC_ARR, val.ADCSAMPLES, val.ADCFRAMES, val.NCHANNELS, 1000, out outdata));
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Great. I did not because I though that it will take less than 1ms. I have checked & it takes about 3ms on my computer.

Comment: @PeterJ to have any kind of realistic data, though, you need way more than just one measurement. And even then, you only have an average, because scheduling depends on many conditions that are outside of your control. Set up a benchmark that starts the task a few thousands times for starters.

Comment: FYI: On my system the **first** `Task.Run(...)` will take about **25ms** and all of the next `Task.Run()` will take about **0ms** (around 50 ticks in average => 1000 ticks = 1ms). On the first task creation there is some sort of initialization of the tread pool and that will take its time. On measurement we had to be careful, what we really going to measure and expect different results in "cold" or "hot" environments.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it depends on a number of conditions.
E.g., if thread pool is depleted, it will wait 0.5-1 seconds for any of existing threads to yield and if none of them is released by this time, it will create an extra thread to run your task.
You can find a pretty exhaustive investigation into the subject [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/FrostRed/archive/2016/08/04/188548.aspx).

Comment: Thank you - but because I have only one background task at the particular moment - I will never run out of free tasks.